# Gnome-shell extension. Working with windows

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

How do I switch windows programmaticly? I mean like Alt+Tab does but without any labels or something.

I tried to look through the documentation but it's too complicated for me ( you can say then not to do it, but I learned action script with help of a good docs although didn't know a thing at first). And I don't complitly understand where exactly to look, because there a lot of libraries and some thing called GObject-Introspection. And when I am trying to find something there, I get lost out there, because I don't realy know what am I looking for. It's kind of a circle)).

I also tried to look at the source codes of other extensions, but it's even more complicated than the documentation. It sounds like I am pretty dummy but I can catch it up.

So, does anybody know how to deal with switching windows, where I can find methods I need in documantation or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The library you seem to looking for is [libwnck](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/).  The library is written in C. However, you can access them in different languages, like JavaScript for the extensions.  This is done via GObject-Instrospection, which at this point you do not need to understand deeply (just that GObject-Introspection is the glue that allows you to use the libraries in different languages).  The prefix usually changes depending of the language.

For your specific purpose, you might want to take a look at [devilpie2](https://github.com/gusnan/devilspie2) instead.